# How to split a file using shell commands in python

Tags: python, shell, file, amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

I have a script that generate a log file then sends it via email (AWS SES).

Sometimes the generated file becomes large and since the limit of the SES is 10MB I need to split the file into smaller files before sending it .
The name of the file is defined:

```
import subprocess
import datetime

fileHandler = os.path.join('/tmp','error-' + datetime.datetime.utcnow().strftime('%Y-%m-%d') + '.log')

subprocess.Popen('split -b 9MB '+fileHandler)
```

When I execute these lines nothing happens to the file and I can't split it. I'm not sure how to execute a shell command when at the same time passing through a python variable (in this case, the variable of `fileHandler`)

Any suggestions please are very appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to documentation of sub-process library we have to pass arguments in form of **list**, which I use all the time to run shell commands, that might be a issue just try this instead. Also use number of bytes in MB instead of MB keyword i.e **9437184** for 9MB.

```
subprocess.Popen(['split','-b','9437184',fileHandler])
```

Hope it will work..

Also split command might need prefix to create new files.

```
split -b 22 newfile.txt new
```

which splits the file newfile.txt into three separate files called newaa, newab and newac..., with each file containing 22 bytes of data.

so you might have to use command

```
subprocess.Popen(['split','-b','9437184',fileHandler,'anyprefix'])
```

Comment: I tried and it didn't work. When I execute it a file appears in the folder, its name is git-index-private-2778 then It disapears again

Comment: ok I tried it in command line and got error that split: **"9MB: invalid number of bytes"**, so instead use number of bytes in MB i.e. 9437184. It worked for me. Check edit in answer again..